# Is there a simple one-line approach to combine the output of an unix command with a file?

Tags: shell, unix, merge, command, cat

I want to combine the header of one text file with another text file. I know I can do it with

```
head -n1 file1.txt > header.txt
cat header.txt file2.txt > file2_withHeader.txt
```

but that generates an unnecessary intermediate file and it's two steps. Is there a way to make it one step without generating an intermediate file?

I was thinking of this

```
cat $(head -n1 file1.txt) file2.txt > file2_withHeader.txt
```

but it does not work because `$(head -n1 file1.txt)` is not a file so it cannot concatenate.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All three of the other answers to this question are good, and since each answers in a different way, it'd be a good exercise to learn each one. [LC-datascientist](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38233683/519360)'s and [Diego](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38233786/519360)'s answer each spawn a subshell, so [λuser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38233579/519360)'s two-line approach, perhaps with `&&` between the two commands, is the most ideal.

If you really want this in one command that doesn't launch a sub-shell, you can use `awk` (mawk):

```
awk 'BEGIN { getline < file1.txt; print } 1' file2.txt
```

`gawk` can do it even more elegantly thanks to the `nextfile` command:

```
gawk '1; NR == FNR { nextfile }' file1.txt file2.txt
```

These do the same thing: the first line of file1.txt and prints it, then prints the entirety of file2.txt.

The `mawk` code uses `getline` to read a single line from a given input into `$0` (in this case; see the man page), we can do that before reading file2.txt.  `1` is true, so this second clause always fires, triggering the default action (`print $0`).

The `gawk` code prints first, then uses `NR == FNR` to determine that you're looking at the first file (the overall number of records (lines) and the current file's number of records is the same), in which case it's already time to move to the second file.

---

For the first three lines, `mawk` needs a loop:

```
awk 'BEGIN { for (i=0;i<3;i++) { getline < file1.txt; print } } 1' file2.txt
```

and `gawk` merely needs another condition:

```
gawk '1; NR == FNR && NR >= 3 { nextfile }' file1.txt file2.txt
```

Comment: Thanks for everyone's suggestions. It has gotten into a really interesting conversation and learning experience for me. If more people have their one-liners or approaches to share I like to hear them.

@Adam Katz, if I want to take more than just the first line of the first file (multiple lines), or say I want to copy lines 2 and 3 from `file1.txt` and add them to the beginning of `file2.txt` using `awk` or `gawk`, how do I change those awk and gawk commands that you've provided?

Comment: I've update the answer with a version that fetches the first three lines.  Just change the number `3` to the number you want.  `gawk` can easily be altered further to specify exact line numbers (`NR == FNR && (NR == 2 || NR == 4)` will get lines 2 and 4 of the first file for example).

Answer (score 1):

You can actually append with the redirections:

```
head -n1 file1.txt > result.txt
cat file2.txt >> result.txt
```

Comment: You can make this "one" line with ampersands (`&&`) or a semicolon (`;`):  `head -n1 file1.txt > result.txt && cat file2.txt >> result.txt`.  The ampersands will prevent running the second command if the first fails.

Answer (score 1):

in `bash` you can also do

```
cat <(head -n 1 file1.txt) file2.txt > file2_withHeader.txt
```

which I think it was you were looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, λuser. That's one option I can do, too.

Actually, I just figured out the one-liner that I was hoping for.

```
(head -n1 file1.txt; cat file2.txt) > file2_withHeader.txt
```

Sorry, I realized this is the same question as others asking to combine two commands in unix, so this has actually been answered.

Comment: You can also use `sed 1q file1.txt | cat - file2.txt > file2_withHeader.txt`.  Using `sed 1q` instead of `head -n1` is cosmetic; using `cat - file2.txt` gets `cat` to read its standard input before reading `file2.txt`.  There are numerous other ways to do it too.  `{ sed 1q file1.txt; cat file2.txt; } > file2_withHeader.txt` is another.

Comment: @LC-datascientist Note that your `(...)` creates another whole process, whereas Jonathan's `{...}` is just a compound statement that gets executed in the current shell so is more efficient. Note too that you need a closing `;` in the `{...}` case.